# One liner for getting a sublist from a Set

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons-collection

Is there a one-liner (maybe from Guava or Apache Collections) that gets a sublist from a set. Internally it should do something like this:

```
public <T> List<T> sublist(Set<T> set, int count) {
  Iterator<T> iterator = set.iterator();
  List<T> sublist = new LinkedList<T>();
  int pos = 0;
  while (iterator.hasNext() && pos++ < count) {
    sublist.add(iterator.next());
  }
  return sublist;
}
```

Obviously, if there are not enough elements it has to return as many as possible.

Comment: If you want `subList` from your collection, you shouldn't use `Set` in first place since its iteration order is **undefined** and your implementation can yield different results depending on... phase of the moon.

Comment: How do you know that order of elements in my `Set` is undefined?

Comment: From Java Collections API - see [iterator() description in `Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()). The `Set` interface itself makes adds nothing to `Collection` contract about iteration order; Set implementations on the other hand [_can_ order its elements somehow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) (TreeSet and LinkedHashSet does).

Comment: How do you know that my `Set` implementation is not adding iteration order to it?

Comment: I don't know your impl, but in method signature there's no `YourSet` but `Set` parameter and thus method can (you don't forbid it) be invoked as `sublist(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(2,3,1), 2)` which _can_ yeild different result than `sublist(new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(2,3,1), 2)`.

Comment: `Set` iteration order is not undefined, as you said above. It may be defined by `Set` interface in any possible way. Keep in mind that `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` are just a few possible implementations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With Guava:

```
return FluentIterable.from(set) 
  .limit(count)
  .toImmutableList();
```

(Also, this won't actually iterate over the whole set, in contrast to most of these other solutions -- it'll *actually* only iterate through the first `count` elements and then stop.)

Comment: +1 'new XXXList(set)' processes ALL elements in Set, FluentIterable does not.

Comment: Starting from Guava 3.0, it's possible to do it as `Iterables.limit(set, count);`. Simpler API, IMHO.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: This approach converts it to a `List`, which I believed was part of the question.

Answer (score 13):

```
(new LinkedList<Object>(mySet)).sublist(0, Math.min(count, mySet.size()))
```

But please note: the code (even your original code) is a little bit smelly, since iteration order of sets depends on the actual set implementation in question (it's totally undefined in `HashSet` and the key order for `TreeSet`s). So, it is actually an open question, which elements make it into the final sublist.

Answer (score 7):

This should do it:

```
return (new LinkedList<T>(set)).subList(0, count);
```

But ensure, that `count` isn't larger than the size of `set`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and use it's [subSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet%28E,%20boolean,%20E,%20boolean%29) method:

> Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements range from fromElement to toElement. If fromElement and toElement are equal, the returned set is empty unless fromExclusive and toExclusive are both true. The returned set is backed by this set, so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa. The returned set supports all optional set operations that this set supports.

**EXAMPLE USING INTEGER:**

```
TreeSet<Integer> t = new TreeSet<Integer>();
t.add(1);
t.add(2);
t.add(3);
t.add(4);
t.add(5);

System.out.println("Before SubSet:");

for(Integer s : t){
    System.out.println(s);
}

System.out.println("\nAfter SubSet:");


for(Integer s : t.subSet(2,false,5,true)){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Before SubSet:
1
2
3
4
5

After SubSet:
3
4
5
```

Alternatively, If you do not know the elements and want to return the elements between two points you can use an ArrayList constructed with the Set and use the [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method.

```
System.out.println("\nAfter SubSet:");

t = new TreeSet(new ArrayList(t).subList(2, 5));

for(Integer s : t){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: that's against the requirements explained above. I don't know the values of elements, I just need to get a number of them

Comment: @yegor256 I do apoligise. I have added a method onto the end which I think may be more along the lines of what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

What about this

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
// add at least two items to the set 
Set<String> subSet = new HashSet(new ArrayList<String>(s).subList(1, 2));
```

This would sublist between 1 and 2

Comment: This concrete snippet would give `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ;)

Comment: @Xaerxess ah yes you are correct. Let me update the code sample. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a copy of the `Set` beforehand, you can do (using Guava) :

```
Lists.newLinkedList(Iterables.getFirst(Iterables.partition(mySet, count), ImmutableList.of()))
```

It's a real `LinkedList` containing only (up to) the first `count` elements, not a view on a larger list.

Answer (score 0):

with java 8

```
set.stream().limit(limit).collect(Collectors.toList());
```